# Insomnia MultiPart Mutation

Tags: java, graphql, schema, multipartform-data, insomnia

[here is another screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smnZZ.png)[here is a screenshot of my Insomnia workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xGrW.png)I'm trying to define my "operations" with type Text(Multi-Line) with this content below :

```
{
  "query": "mutation ($number: String! $countr: String! $image: Upload!){
    create(number: $number, countr: $countr, image: $image){
      id,
      timestamp
    }
  }",
  "variables": {
    "number": "99999",
    "countr": "Abc",
    "image": null
  }
}
```

but Insomnia notify me this below :

> Parse error on line2: {"query": "mutation ($number:---------^ "Expecting" : "STRING", "NUMBER", "{", "[", "UNDEFINED", ...

but once I sendind the query, I'm receiving this below :

> {
> "timestamp": 1602665134654,
> "status": 422,
> "error": "Unprocessable Entity",
> "message": "",
> "path": "/graphql"
> }

Can someone help me tofix this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: server mutation signature? not matches with this query? ... if `Upload!` then no null for 'image' allowed

Comment: Hi, thk for your reply! Yes my mutation signature matches this query and I removed this (!) on Upload but didn't work. I already get this below: {
  "timestamp": 1602672547359,
  "status": 422,
  "error": "Unprocessable Entity",
  "message": "",
  "path": "/graphql"
}

Comment: My content-type is multipart/form-data. I don't know if it's correct

Comment: still ... **show server mutation signature!!!** [proofs, not declarations] ... if no upload then no multipart ... maybe you must provide a file for this mutation

Comment: create(number: String!, countr: String!, file: Upload): Ticket! and type Ticket { id timeStmp}. That is the signature of my mutation and the return type. Thk you

Comment: I also define a 'scalar Upload' in my schema

Comment: file is not required then change  '$image: Upload!' to `$file: Upload` (remove `!` - not required variable, and `file` not `image` later), don't pass 'file' variable (leave undefined) ... send as json ... for file included send as multipart

Comment: I also add 2  content-type : the first is application/json and the second one is multipart/form-data but I also have the same ouput {
  "timestamp": 1602678539801,
  "status": 422,
  "error": "Unprocessable Entity",
  "message": "",
  "path": "/graphql"
} and my server don't receive this request. I also move this image in my schema and replaced it by file. I you can see the picture that I added to the post.

Comment: one content-type, conditionaly, json if no file, multipart if file defined ... update query in question to current state

Comment: Thk! I make it but did not work

Comment: The main problem is that I want to have an object as return and inside this object the url whee I stored my image.

Answer (score 0):

Define "operations" with **JUST** Text type.

I'm not sure of your business logic, but if you use `DefaultGraphQLServletContext.getFileParts()`, then this method will judge the "operations" as a file not a text.